# increasing number of partitions for a spark-submit job

Tags: apache-spark

We are running a spark-submit command to work on 100GB data on 12 cores. The command is creating 18 tasks because of which it is taking lot of time. We want to increase the number of partition to increase the number of tasks for decreasing the time. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

The number of partitions is usually derived from your data source and changed to 200 when you do the first shuffle.

You can repartition in the code at any point. Both rdd and dataframe have the repartition method (rdd also has repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions and dataframe's repartition can provide columns to partition by which you should use in order to make sure you are repartitioning according to the relevant columns).

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, Can you please explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted it, but I like your answer, so here's an upvote :)